Symbolising an following argument with two Therefore's
I am trying to translate the following argument to logic symbols to verify its validity using truth tables:

If the supplier supplies the seeds, then if the seeds are sown on time, then the plants will sprout in August. The seeds are sown on time. Therefore, if the supplier supplies the seeds, then the seeds will be sown on time. Therefore, if the plants do not sprout in August, then the supplier will not supply the seeds.

P: 'The supplier supplies the seeds.'
Q: 'The seeds are sown on time.'
R: 'The plants will sprout in August.'

I think the argument could be written as three premises and a conclusion as follows:
$1.P\Rightarrow(Q\Rightarrow R)\\
2.Q\\
3.P\Rightarrow Q\\
\therefore\neg R\Rightarrow\neg P.$
So, the argument could be written as:
$\big[\big\{[P\Rightarrow(Q\Rightarrow R)]\land Q\big\}\land (P\Rightarrow Q)\big]\Rightarrow (\neg R\Rightarrow\neg P)$
I have doubts about the expression above because of the two "therefore"s in the argument. I think the second $\land$ replaces $\Rightarrow,$ but I'm not sure about this.

You are making predictions about the future. There may be times in August when the seeds have not yet sprouted and other times when they have sprouted. How, for example, can we assign a truth value in the present to, "The plants will sprout in next month." A simple truth table would not be sufficient. I think some kind of temporal or causal logic is required here.

Necessary conditions for the plants to sprout in August: (1) Seeds received by July 1. (2) Seeds are sown by July 7. How can we determine if this is true?

Other necessary conditions: sufficient rain, adequate soil.

If plants sprout in August, then (1) and (2) must be true.

(1/2) @DanChristensen "There may be times in August when the seeds have not yet sprouted and other times when they have sprouted."  IMO that is irrelevant to the present problem where "plants (will) sprout in August" is simply atomic, and it's in fact either true or false here and now: that such and such plants sprout in such and such period, given such and such conditions.

(2/2) But even where a notion of time is relevant to an argument, we can formalize what is relevant in terms of relations.  Indeed, Temporal Logic might be a more natural way to express temporal relationships, on the other hand arguably Logic in general needn't be concerned with temporality any more than it needs be concerned with spatiality or any other contingent/material notions...

@JulioDiEgidio How can we say in the present that a prediction about the future is true or false? In the present, it's truth value is indeterminate. We cannot, for example, attach a truth value to the prediction that, tomorrow, it will rain where you are. IIUC the best you can do is to calculate the probability of rain tomorrow given current weather conditions and past history for similar conditions. You might say, for example, "Under similar conditions in the past, it rained 30% of the time.

@DanChristensen  You might think there is a "typically" or an "expectedly" or similar involved, but it doesn't matter: besides that nothing is absolute about what we ever may say in any case, the present one is just an elementary exercise in formalization, so the text should just be taken at face value, i.e. quite literally.  --  Similarly to mathematics: take e.g. a balls and vase problem, you are not going to ask how big the vase is or how much the balls weigh or anything of that sort, you just take it at face value and try and answer the counting question.

In the context of introductory logic, an argument is often defined as consisting of any number of premises, and exactly 1 conclusion.  However, it seems that in this case, the argument is seen as a piece of reasoning, i.e. a larger structure that has intermediate results between the premises and the conclusion. In particular, the third sentence (which follows the first 'therefore') seems to be an intermediate result, which is then used to get to the ultimate conclusion (the statement following the second 'therefore'), which is the fourth sentence. That is, it looks something like:
$1. P \to (Q \to R) \ \text{(Premise)}$
$2. Q \ \text{(Premise)}$
$3. P \to Q \ \text{(Intermediate result)}$
$4. \neg R \to \neg P \ \text{(Conclusion)}$
And this makes some sense:  sentence $3$ follows immediately from sentence 2, since any conditional is true as soon as its consequent is true.  And sentence 4 is then  inferred from 1 and 3: If we had $P$, then by 3 we'd have $Q$ as well, and hence by 1 we'd have $R$. So, if we don't have $R$, we can't have $P$ either. So we have:
$1. P \to (Q \to R) \ \text{(Premise)}$
$2. Q \ \text{(Premise)}$
$3. P \to Q \ \text{(Intermediate result from 2)}$
$4. \neg R \to \neg P \ \text{(Conclusion from 1 and 3)}$
Now, to verify this argument is valid, we can do 2 things: we can either follow this detailed structure of the argument, and verify that both steps are valid. Thus, we can set up 2 truth-tables: one truth-table which verifies that from $Q$ you can validly infer $P \to Q$, and a second truth-table which verifies that from $P \to (Q \to R)$ and $P \to Q$ you can validly infer $\neg R \to \neg P$.
Alternatively, we can simply stick to the premises and the ultimate conclusion, and use just 1 truth-table, which verifies that from $P \to (Q \to R)$ and $Q$ you can validly infer $\neg R \to \neg P$.
My preference would be with the first method as it recognizes the step-by-step reasoning that is taking place here. Indeed, something that could have happened is that the intermediate result as stated by the argument would not validly follow from the premises, even though the ultimate conclusion does. In that case, I would find the argument (as in the piece of reasoning or proof) to be invalid, rather than valid.

Thanks @Bram28. I really appreciate the answers each one provides.

@Trascendence Which is equivalent to mine except without the formality.-  But thanks especially Bram28, 101k reputation, for (not even) pointing that out: what the heck I am even wasting my time with...


P: 'The supplier supplies the seeds.'
Q: 'The seeds are sown on time.'
R: 'The plants will sprout in August.'


If the supplier supplies the seeds, then if the seeds are sown on time, then the plants will sprout in August. The seeds are sown on time. Therefore, if the supplier supplies the seeds, then the seeds will be sown on time. Therefore, if the plants do not sprout in August, then the supplier will not supply the seeds.


The argument is just $$(P → (Q→R)) \;∧\; Q \quad→\quad (¬R → ¬P),$$ and it is indeed valid.
Do note that the boldfaced phrases in the verbal argument are inaccurate and should be changed to "are not" and "does not", respectively.

How do you avoid the intermediate "therefore"?  I was rather inclined to translate that text as two theorems...

@JulioDiEgidio The OP has given a single argument with ostensibly one (final) conclusion. From the wrong tenses, I assume that only the two premises are quoted from the source material, in which case it seems that the OP is suspecting that their intermediate steps/derivations should be presented with the premises; I'm pointing out that the countless possible sentences, like (P→R), derivable from the two premises, don't need to be considered conclusion/(redundant)premises.

For the sake of argument, I find your reduction rather unwarranted.  Moreover, the OP ostensibly is not doing that, just look at their proposed formalization, which I think botches few connectors, but otherwise is in line with the informal text and does not drop anything.

Here is a take where I am just formalizing "along the way", i.e. phrase by phrase (it may not be that simple with more complex text).
Few notes:

I am taking each "therefore" to be indicating that the conclusion of a theorem is meant. -- Whether this is really adequate should be clearer by actually reading the article or book, what the author means.

I am not attaching a particular significance to the verb tenses. -- I agree the present tense everywhere might have been more appropriate, if not an appropriate use of tenses, anyway the presentation is at least uniform in that every conclusion is put in the future tense.

I have used axioms to represent the hypotheses, but assumptions to the same effect in each theorem would have been equivalent.

The formalization is constructive in Coq (namely, not using Excluded Middle or similar), both proofs are very simple. -- I have added few comments and hope the code is readable enough, anyway feel free to ask for clarifications.


(* Coq 8.18.0 *)

(**
  P := "The supplier supplies the seeds."
  Q := "The seeds are sown on time."
  R := "The plants will sprout in August."
*)
Parameters P Q R : Prop.

(**
  If the supplier supplies the seeds,
  then if the seeds are sown on time,
  then the plants will sprout in August.
*)
Axiom Ax_PQR : P -> (Q -> R).

(**
  The seeds are sown on time.
*)
Axiom Ax_Q : Q.

(**
  Therefore, if the supplier supplies the
  seeds, then the seeds will be sown on time.
*)
Lemma Th_PQ : P -> Q.
Proof.
  (** Trivial by [Ax_Q]. *)
  intros _.
  (* [|- Q] *)
  exact Ax_Q.
Qed.

(**
  Therefore, if the plants do not sprout in
  August, then the supplier will not supply
  the seeds.
*)
Lemma Th_nRnP : ~ R -> ~ P.
Proof.
  (** Amounts to P -> R, then
     by [Ax_PQR] we get trivial goals. *)
  intros HnR HP.
  destruct HnR.
  (* [HP : P |- R] *)
  apply Ax_PQR.  (* backwards MP *)
  - (* [HP : P |- P] *)
    exact HP.
  - (* [HP : P |- Q] *)
    exact Ax_Q.
Qed.

Of course, especially in hindsight (in fact, especially considering that the second theorem can be proved without relying on the first), the same formalization can be packed into a single, self-contained statement.  Here it is for comparison:
Goal forall P Q R : Prop,
  ((P -> Q -> R) /\ Q) ->
  (P -> Q) /\ (~ R -> ~ P).
Proof.
  intros P Q R [HPQR HQ].
  split.  (* prove each conjunct *)
  - (*  P, Q, R : Prop
        HPQR : P -> Q -> R
        HQ : Q
        ------------------
        P -> Q *)
    intros _.
    exact HQ.
  - (*  P, Q, R : Prop
        HPQR : P -> Q -> R
        HQ : Q
        ------------------
        ~ R -> ~ P *)
    intros HnR HP.
    destruct HnR.
    exact (HPQR HP HQ).
Qed.

Although, I think a truly faithful self-contained single statement, where precedence of theorems is respected, would look like the following (which, in this specific case, remains as simple to prove as above):
Goal forall P Q R : Prop,
  ((P -> Q -> R) /\ Q) ->
  (P -> Q) /\ ((P -> Q) -> (~ R -> ~ P)).

As said, overall taking each "therefore" as indicating a theorem.

Many thanks to whomever downvoted this. This place is just a complete shithole as the rest of SE is, and as it all must be because what else can you get from a fake and abusive pseudo-democracy just based on personal interest and property, if not a shithole for everybody...


If the supplier supplies the seeds, then if the seeds are sown on
time, then the plants will sprout in August.

A poor example. Call it nitpicking, but in reality, that should be, if the plants sprout in August then the seeds will have been supplied and sown on time.
Seeds being supplied and sown on time are necessary, but not sufficient conditions for the plants to sprout in August.
IMHO authors often do a poor job of providing such "real-world" translation exercises. To avoid confusion, they might consider using only statements about present conditions.
My favourite example:
$R~\equiv ~$ It is raining (present tense)
$C~\equiv ~$ It is cloudy (present tense)
$(R \implies C) ~\equiv ~ \neg (R \land \neg C) ~ \equiv ~$ Presently, it is not the case that it is both raining and not cloudy.
This is entirely consistent with the truth table:

Anyway, if you insist that having the seeds being supplied and sown on time is sufficient for the plants sprouting in August, then if the plants did NOT sprout in August, you could infer that it is not the case that the seeds were supplied and sown on time.
